# Upgrading spring cloud version from Edgware to Hoxton

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-cloud

I am upgrade spring boot version from `1.5.9` to `2.3.5` and spring cloud version from `Edgware.SR2` to `Hoxton.SR6`.

`POM` included `spring-cloud-stream-schema`, `spring-cloud-starter-eureka` and `spring-cloud-sleuth-stream` like below when it runs with `Edgware`.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-schema</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

After the upgrade, maven build gives below error.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-schema:jar is missing. @ line 89, column 15
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka:jar is missing. @ line 97, column 15
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-stream:jar is missing. @ line 109, column 15
```

Looks like these 3 jars are moved out or merge with others in `Hoxton.SR6`.

What would be the updated dependencies?

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2018/06/19/spring-cloud-finchley-release-is-available

Comment: Are you importing your dependencies (versions) via the `spring-cloud-dependencies` BOM?

Comment: @DirkDeyne no. spring-boot-starter-parent

Answer (score 1):

These dependencies are not supported now in **Spring Boot version 2.x.**

Add these updated dependencies in **pom.xml** :

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Full sample **pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.so</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR9</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <classifier>test-binder</classifier>
            <type>test-jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Note:** Change cloud version to `Horton.SR9`

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-schema-registry-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: `import org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.Span;`
`import org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.log.Slf4jSpanLogger;`
How to satisfy the these two imports? changing `spring-cloud-sleuth-stream` to `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth` is not satisfy the dependency...

Answer (score 0):

You might consider replacing these artefacts as follows:

1. `spring-cloud-stream-schema`: in [this commit](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-starters/commit/c248a36791ebd1a816082ee0199f45f1890aa4fd) it was changed to `spring-cloud-schema-registry-core` as it's coordinates changed. Consider using that one instead.
2. `spring-cloud-starter-eureka`: this starter is deprecated and was removed from the BOM [in this commit](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/commit/c511440ed9e87b2195f447e3dfd4201a4d8f8dca) you might consider switching to `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client`.
3. `spring-cloud-sleuth-stream`: it is deprecated and should not longer be used. I would recommend you to try to get rid of it as it is incompatible with some destinations or just add the version number you want to use at your own risk until you can get remove it. The version in the BOM of the Spring Cloud release you were using is `1.3.2.RELEASE`.